# Is there a single IP address for my Netlify site (custom domain enabled)

Tags: azure-api-management, netlify

I have RESTful API hosted on Azure. In order to restrict the access to it instead of implementing authentication/authorization I’ve decided to place it behind [API Management service (APIM)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/services/api-management/) and set an IP filter.

[image]

My ultimate goal is to allow only my Netlify hosted site to access it. But in order to do that I will need to make sure that my site is behind a single IP address and it doesn’t change. The reason for that is that I’ve noticed multiple cases where people are making reference to my API (probably from Postman, CURL or whatever HTTP issuer) without visiting my website.

Disclaimer: I am not a networking expert. I suppose that my site probably gets hosted dynamically on different IP addresses but anyways I decided to reach out for help.

Is it possible to achieve what I am looking for?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [Profile - fool - Netlify Support Forums](https://answers.netlify.com/u/fool). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help other community members.

> The only static IP we have is our load balancer, but that is only for incoming traffic; since that is a group of CDN nodes and each individual CDN node has its own IP for outgoing connections, such as ones to your site when you proxy to it from our service. We do not publish that address list anywhere (and it changes a lot.)

References: [Is there a single IP address for my Netlify site (custom domain enabled) - Support - Netlify Support Forums](https://answers.netlify.com/t/is-there-a-single-ip-address-for-my-netlify-site-custom-domain-enabled/53168) and [Rewrites and proxies | Netlify Docs](https://docs.netlify.com/routing/redirects/rewrites-proxies/#signed-proxy-redirects)